# how to revert a bunch of patches combined in one commit that was already pushed to staging?

Tags: git, github

The situation is like this,
I was in development branch. Then I did `git format-patch staging` so it generated a lot of .patch file since I have working on this big module for 2 months and none has been pushed to staging. Now that the patch files have been generated, I checked out staging branch and applied each of the patch via `git am --3way the-name-of-the-patch-file.patch` . with that --3way git command, the patch that was applied is being committed automatically if there's no conflict. Then in order to minimize flooding the github desktop client with too many commits of the patches, I did `git log --oneline` to see all the head of the commits in staging ordered in descending and did `git reset the-head-of-the-last-commit-before-my-first-patch`. Then all of my patched files went untracked, and so I added each of them to be committed. So after I committed and pushed, I now only have one commit/push in staging that contains all of my commits of the patches , the problem is, I missed something in one of the files. I forgot to remove the `=======adf234235` during the time I was applying the patches and now it's causing syntax error. The question now is, How to remove my pushed commit to staging so that I can re-apply the patches again and make sure everything will be correct already?

note:I am not the only user of the repo. please suggest a safe way to solve this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you don't want to remove or change any commits that have already been pushed. Just push a new commit that fixes the issue, and then tell anyone using the repo to pull again.

See here for some more discussion about changing pushed commits:
http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html

Comment: Thing is, the sysop wants each dev to have one git hash only from their part regardless of how many files you change....so if am gonna commit again to staging, that's equivalent to two git hash already